# Is it possible to upgrade the smart contract (currency token)?

Tags: tokens

Suppose as the time goes by we, as token developers, acknowledged that we did some stupid mistakes in the initial contract, or, for example decided to add some new features. Is it possible to upgrade our contract? What will happen to the tokens that are already circulating around the network?

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

1.- Export token balances, kill the current contract and create a new one implementing old balances.

2.- Delegate the token balance on a different contract that remains after killing the token contract, and link the new token contract to the balance again.

Comment: But isn't a wallet for the given token associated with an address of the token contract?

Comment: As far as I know, the only wallet associated to the token is the contract owner's.